# How does one find out whether a particular Intercités train on a particular route requires reservation?

Tags: trains, tickets, france, sncf

How does one find out whether a particular Intercités train on a particular route requires a reservation?

Answer (score 6):

On [SNCF website for Intercités trains](http://www.intercites.sncf.com/trains-et-services/intercites), one can find a map of all *Intercités de Jour* with different line style for those with required reservations.

Giving a quick look at it, this does not seem to follow a specific logic, some lines having both, some lines having only either with or without reservation. There is no geographical logic either.

Answer (score 3):

You can look up the timetables on [the *Intercités* website](http://www.intercites.sncf.com/reseau-intercites/lignes-intercites-lunea-teoz). *Intercité* trains with compulsory reservation are marked with a R in a box above the train number. In addition, all *Intercité de nuit* (night trains) and *TGV* (high-speed trains) require a reservation, and *TER* (regional trains) never do.

On the [train booking interface](http://en.voyages-sncf.com/), you'll find the indication “mandatory seat reservation” where applicable. You'll find the same information on the [Deutsche Bahn](http://www.bahn.de/) and other websites.

For the most part, trains with the same endpoints have the same status (e.g. no Paris–Nevers train requires a reservation, whereas all Paris–Clermont-Ferrand trains require a reservation even if you get off at Nevers). Beware that there are occasional exceptions.